# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllParts' of undefined at allParts ..\\resolvers.js:6:62)",

Tags: graphql, sqldatasource, apollo-server

I am having trouble figuring out why the object whos property is getting called is undefined. I am using graphql, apollo-server, and the following Data Source type https://github.com/cvburgess/SQLDataSource.

I've searched several posts but nothing I found helped.

I know that is has to do with something not being passed correctly. I just dont understand why it's not being passed correctly.

resolvers.js

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
       //getPart: (_,{itemnum},{dataSources}) => dataSources.partAPI.getPart({itemnum: itemnum}),
       allParts: (_,__,{dataSources}) => dataSources.partAPI.getAllParts(),
      },
};

module.exports = resolvers
```

and here is the rest of my code

Index.js

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const resolvers = require ('./resolvers')
const PartAPI = require ('./datasources/part');

const knexConfig = {
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: {
    /* CONNECTION INFO */
    filename: "./TEAM_material.db3"
  }
};

  const db = new PartAPI(knexConfig);

const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => ({db}),
    introspection: true,
 });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
  });
```

Schema.js

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')

const typeDefs = gql`
#Types
    type Part {
        itemnum: String!
        desc: String!
        vendor: String!
        manuf: String!
        venlist: Float!
        price: Float!
        teamlist: Float!
        teamsell: Float!
        unitypart: String!
        pkgqty: Int!
        ioType: String!
        preferred: Boolean!
        filterlvl1: String!
        filterlvl2: String!
        filterlvl3: String!
        filterlvl4: String!
        ipwiretype: String!
        opwiretype: String!
        obsolete: Boolean!
    }
#Queries
    type Query {
        getPart(itemnum: String!): Part
        allParts: [Part!]!
    }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs
```

part.js

```
const { SQLDataSource } = require("datasource-sql");



const MINUTE = 60;

class PartAPI extends SQLDataSource {

    async getPart({itemnum}){
        return this.knex.select("*").from("part").where('itemnum', itemnum).cache(60);
    }

    async getAllParts(){
        return this.knex.select("*").from("part").cache(MINUTE);
    }
}

module.exports = PartAPI;
```

Comment: Where do you get `this.knex` from in your `PartAPI` class?

Comment: Why would you expect `dataSources` to have a property on it named `partAPI`? Take a look at the function that you're passing to your ApolloServer constructor -- what does that function return? Based on that, what sort of properties would you expect `dataSources` do have?

Comment: @goto1 the SQLDataSrouce type that I am extending has a this.knex property. You can see this property in the implementation of SQLDataSource in the Github link provided. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: @DanielRearden that you so much for the help. I realized that I wasn't actually giving dataSources a partAPI property.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Rearden. Thank you for the help. From what you said, I was able to deduce that I need to pass this into the APolloServer constructor instead.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => ({
      partAPI: new PartAPI(knexConfig),
    }),
    introspection: true,
 });
```